# Can't log in via SSH using keys - fails at preauth

Tags: ssh

I've been using linux for a number of years, yet I'm at a loss to as why this won't work correctly. All permissions to me appear correctly but I must be missing something obvious somewhere.

I can login via password normally, and falling back to password also works.

Log from the server:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ tail -f /var/log/auth.log
Aug 17 14:39:47 raspberrypi sshd[3725]: debug1: trying public key file /home/pi/.ssh/authorized_keys
Aug 17 14:39:47 raspberrypi sshd[3725]: debug1: fd 4 clearing O_NONBLOCK
Aug 17 14:39:47 raspberrypi sshd[3725]: debug1: restore_uid: 0/0
Aug 17 14:39:47 raspberrypi sshd[3725]: Failed publickey for pi from 192.168.1.12 port 42069 ssh2
Aug 17 14:40:44 raspberrypi sshd[3725]: Connection closed by 192.168.1.12 [preauth]
Aug 17 14:40:44 raspberrypi sshd[3725]: debug1: do_cleanup [preauth]
Aug 17 14:40:44 raspberrypi sshd[3725]: debug1: monitor_read_log: child log fd closed
Aug 17 14:40:44 raspberrypi sshd[3725]: debug1: do_cleanup
Aug 17 14:40:44 raspberrypi sshd[3725]: debug1: PAM: cleanup
Aug 17 14:40:44 raspberrypi sshd[3725]: debug1: Killing privsep child 3728






Aug 17 14:42:22 raspberrypi sudo:       pi : TTY=tty1 ; PWD=/home/pi ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/etc/init.d/ssh restart
Aug 17 14:42:22 raspberrypi sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by pi(uid=0)
Aug 17 14:42:23 raspberrypi sshd[3670]: Received signal 15; terminating.
Aug 17 14:42:23 raspberrypi sshd[3758]: Set /proc/self/oom_score_adj from 0 to -1000
Aug 17 14:42:23 raspberrypi sshd[3758]: debug1: Bind to port 22 on 0.0.0.0.
Aug 17 14:42:23 raspberrypi sshd[3758]: Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.
Aug 17 14:42:23 raspberrypi sshd[3758]: socket: Address family not supported by protocol
Aug 17 14:42:23 raspberrypi sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Aug 17 14:44:46 raspberrypi sshd[3758]: debug1: Forked child 3783.
Aug 17 14:44:46 raspberrypi sshd[3783]: Set /proc/self/oom_score_adj to 0
Aug 17 14:44:46 raspberrypi sshd[3783]: debug1: rexec start in 4 out 4 newsock 4 pipe 6 sock 7
Aug 17 14:44:46 raspberrypi sshd[3783]: debug1: inetd sockets after dupping: 3, 3
Aug 17 14:44:46 raspberrypi sshd[3783]: Connection from 192.168.1.12 port 42126
Aug 17 14:44:47 raspberrypi sshd[3783]: debug1: Client protocol version 2.0; client software version OpenSSH_6.6p1-hpn14v4
Aug 17 14:44:47 raspberrypi sshd[3783]: debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.6p1-hpn14v4 pat OpenSSH*
Aug 17 14:44:47 raspberrypi sshd[3783]: debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
Aug 17 14:44:47 raspberrypi sshd[3783]: debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-4+deb7u2
Aug 17 14:44:47 raspberrypi sshd[3783]: debug1: permanently_set_uid: 101/65534 [preauth]
Aug 17 14:44:47 raspberrypi sshd[3783]: debug1: list_hostkey_types: ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 [preauth]
Aug 17 14:44:47 raspberrypi sshd[3783]: debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent [preauth]
Aug 17 14:44:47 raspberrypi sshd[3783]: debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received [preauth]
Aug 17 14:44:47 raspberrypi sshd[3783]: debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none [preauth]
Aug 17 14:44:47 raspberrypi sshd[3783]: debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none [preauth]
Aug 17 14:44:47 raspberrypi sshd[3783]: debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT [preauth]
Aug 17 14:44:47 raspberrypi sshd[3783]: debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent [preauth]
Aug 17 14:44:47 raspberrypi sshd[3783]: debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS [preauth]
Aug 17 14:44:47 raspberrypi sshd[3783]: debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received [preauth]
Aug 17 14:44:47 raspberrypi sshd[3783]: debug1: KEX done [preauth]
Aug 17 14:44:47 raspberrypi sshd[3783]: debug1: userauth-request for user pi service ssh-connection method none [preauth]
Aug 17 14:44:47 raspberrypi sshd[3783]: debug1: attempt 0 failures 0 [preauth]
Aug 17 14:44:47 raspberrypi sshd[3783]: debug1: PAM: initializing for "pi"
Aug 17 14:44:47 raspberrypi sshd[3783]: debug1: PAM: setting PAM_RHOST to "192.168.1.12"
Aug 17 14:44:47 raspberrypi sshd[3783]: debug1: PAM: setting PAM_TTY to "ssh"
Aug 17 14:44:47 raspberrypi sshd[3783]: debug1: userauth-request for user pi service ssh-connection method publickey [preauth]
Aug 17 14:44:47 raspberrypi sshd[3783]: debug1: attempt 1 failures 0 [preauth]
Aug 17 14:44:47 raspberrypi sshd[3783]: debug1: test whether pkalg/pkblob are acceptable [preauth]
Aug 17 14:44:47 raspberrypi sshd[3783]: debug1: Checking blacklist file /usr/share/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
Aug 17 14:44:47 raspberrypi sshd[3783]: debug1: Checking blacklist file /etc/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
Aug 17 14:44:47 raspberrypi sshd[3783]: debug1: temporarily_use_uid: 1000/1000 (e=0/0)
Aug 17 14:44:47 raspberrypi sshd[3783]: debug1: trying public key file /home/pi/.ssh/authorized_keys
Aug 17 14:44:47 raspberrypi sshd[3783]: debug1: fd 4 clearing O_NONBLOCK
Aug 17 14:44:47 raspberrypi sshd[3783]: debug1: restore_uid: 0/0
Aug 17 14:44:47 raspberrypi sshd[3783]: Failed publickey for pi from 192.168.1.12 port 42126 ssh2
```

Log from the client:

```
tim@MushaV3 ~ $ ssh raspi -v
OpenSSH_6.6, OpenSSL 1.0.1i 6 Aug 2014
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/tim/.ssh/config
debug1: /home/tim/.ssh/config line 29: Applying options for raspi
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Hostname has changed; re-reading configuration
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/tim/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.1.47 [192.168.1.47] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/tim/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /home/tim/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6p1-hpn14v4
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-4+deb7u2
debug1: Remote is NON-HPN aware
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-4+deb7u2 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x14000000
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: AUTH STATE IS 0
debug1: REQUESTED ENC.NAME is 'aes128-ctr'
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: REQUESTED ENC.NAME is 'aes128-ctr'
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ECDSA 62:72:a3:8f:fb:c7:58:45:5b:b9:67:5a:ac:81:4f:be
debug1: Host '192.168.1.47' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/tim/.ssh/known_hosts:31
debug1: ssh_ecdsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/tim/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
pi@192.168.1.47's password:
```

Client file permissions:

```
tim@MushaV3 ~ $ ls -lah ./.ssh/
total 48K
drwx------  2 tim tim 4.0K Aug 17 15:35 .
drwxr-xr-x 77 tim tim 4.0K Aug 16 11:41 ..
-rw-------  1 tim tim 1.7K Mar 23  2013 amazonkey.pem
-rw-------  1 tim tim 1.6K Oct 20  2013 authorized_keys
-rw-r--r--  1 tim tim  415 Aug 17 15:31 config
-rw-------  1 tim tim 1.7K Jun 26 00:30 id_OVH
-rw-r--r--  1 tim tim  393 Jun 26 00:30 id_OVH.pub
-rw-------  1 tim tim 1.7K Aug 27  2011 id_rsa
-rw-r--r--  1 tim tim  393 Aug 27  2011 id_rsa.pub
-rw-r--r--  1 tim tim 8.6K Aug 17 15:00 known_hosts
```

Server file permissions:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ ls -lah ./.ssh/
total 16K
drwxr-xr-x 2 pi pi 4.0K Aug 17 14:13 .
drwxr-xr-x 5 pi pi 4.0K Aug 17 14:00 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 pi pi  393 Aug 17 14:00 authorized_keys
-rw-r--r-- 1 pi pi  444 Aug 17 14:27 known_hosts
```

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ ls -lah /etc/ssh/
total 180K
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4.0K Aug 17 14:22 .
drwxr-xr-x 99 root root 4.0K Aug 17 13:59 ..
-rw-------  1 root root 133K Feb 19  2013 moduli
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1.7K Feb 19  2013 ssh_config
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 2.5K Aug 17 14:38 sshd_config
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 2.5K Aug 17 14:11 sshd_config.save
-rw-------  1 root root  668 Aug 17 14:19 ssh_host_dsa_key
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  606 Aug 17 14:19 ssh_host_dsa_key.pub
-rw-------  1 root root  227 Jan  7  2014 ssh_host_ecdsa_key
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  178 Jan  7  2014 ssh_host_ecdsa_key.pub
-rw-------  1 root root  981 Aug 17 14:18 ssh_host_rsa_key
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  646 Aug 17 14:18 ssh_host_rsa_key.pub
```

Server config file

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ cat /etc/ssh/sshd_config
# Package generated configuration file
# See the sshd_config(5) manpage for details

# What ports, IPs and protocols we listen for
Port 22
# Use these options to restrict which interfaces/protocols sshd will bind to
#ListenAddress ::
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
Protocol 2
# HostKeys for protocol version 2
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
#Privilege Separation is turned on for security
UsePrivilegeSeparation yes

# Lifetime and size of ephemeral version 1 server key
KeyRegenerationInterval 3600
ServerKeyBits 768

# Logging
SyslogFacility AUTH
LogLevel DEBUG

# Authentication:
LoginGraceTime 120
PermitRootLogin no
# StrictModes yes

RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
AuthorizedKeysFile  .ssh/authorized_keys

# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files
IgnoreRhosts yes
# For this to work you will also need host keys in /etc/ssh_known_hosts
RhostsRSAAuthentication no
# similar for protocol version 2
HostbasedAuthentication no
# Uncomment if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for RhostsRSAAuthentication
#IgnoreUserKnownHosts yes

# To enable empty passwords, change to yes (NOT RECOMMENDED)
PermitEmptyPasswords no

# Change to yes to enable challenge-response passwords (beware issues with
# some PAM modules and threads)
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no

# Change to no to disable tunnelled clear text passwords
PasswordAuthentication yes

# Kerberos options
KerberosAuthentication no
#KerberosGetAFSToken no
#KerberosOrLocalPasswd yes
#KerberosTicketCleanup yes

# GSSAPI options
GSSAPIAuthentication no
#GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes

X11Forwarding yes
X11DisplayOffset 10
PrintMotd no
PrintLastLog yes
TCPKeepAlive yes
#UseLogin no

#MaxStartups 10:30:60
#Banner /etc/issue.net

# Allow client to pass locale environment variables
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*

# Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server

# Set this to 'yes' to enable PAM authentication, account processing,
# and session processing. If this is enabled, PAM authentication will
# be allowed through the ChallengeResponseAuthentication and
# PasswordAuthentication.  Depending on your PAM configuration,
# PAM authentication via ChallengeResponseAuthentication may bypass
# the setting of "PermitRootLogin without-password".
# If you just want the PAM account and session checks to run without
# PAM authentication, then enable this but set PasswordAuthentication
# and ChallengeResponseAuthentication to 'no'.
UsePAM yes
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whoops...

So ssh-copy-id didn't copy the correct key, and then told me it had copied all keys to the host.

Upon adding the correct key manually to authorized_keys it worked!.

**BUG NOTICE** If ssh-copy-id can't access the server, it'll report it's not copied any keys as they were already on the server.

Comment: ssh -v <other stuff> will give you verbose mode, and tell you where ssh fails... Before you go ransacking your logs next time.

Comment: ssh -v wasn't helping in the slightest, it told me it send the key and it was rejected. I rather stupidly presumed all the keys were copied to the server (because ssh-copy-id told me it had) and this is where the failure occured.